# LiveServer working but displaying an error

Tags: javascript, vscode-extensions, liveserver

Whenever I start my live server through VScode in the console of the browser an error message is displayed. but the live server works fine but I don't want to see the the error message how can I fix it
This is the error message

[image]

I tried reinstalling the LiveServer extension but the error is still there